# PYTHON 3 How to stack and delay execution

Tags: python, timer, stack, queue

I'm currently trying to find the good way to stack some information to process them later. But I need to process that information with a delay.

For now, I use the Queue library to stack all the information. I need to set a timer or a thing like this, to control more or less the execution after the information was stacked.

Thanks in advance, hope I was clear enough

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could sleep fit your need?

```
from time import sleep
...
sleep(0.1)
```

This will add a 100 milliseconds delay